# Get argument in an SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, arguments

I'm working with atvise (atvise.com) a JS Platform for Building Automation Systems. The views are generated in SVG-Files. There are Parameter in these SVG Files which I's like to access...

The SVG-Elements look like:

```
     <svg width="88.23" x="230" y="190" onmousedown="alert("THE VALUE OF THE ATV:ARGUMENT")" atvise:base="base" height="150" xlink:href="ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Bsk._right" id="id_40" atv:refpx="233.102" atv:refpy="541.333">
            <atv:argument value="AGENT.OBJECTS.Test.SVH02_6.L01.Bsk.Bsk265Y1" name="base"/>
     </svg>
```

And I would like to make an Alert onmousedown and the content should be the Value-Parameter "AGENT.OBJECTS.Test.SVH02_6.L01.Bsk.Bsk265Y1" which is in the SVG that i click...

I tried things like:

```
onmousedown="alert(evt.target.getArgument(...))"
```

But I was not able to get the Parameter Value of the atv:argument...

Any Ideas, solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg width="88.23" x="230" y="190"
     onmousedown="alert(this.getElementsByTagName('atv:argument')[0].getAttribute('value'))" 
     atvise:base="base"
     height="150"
     xlink:href="ObjectTypes.PROJECT.Bsk._right"
     id="id_40"
     atv:refpx="233.102"
     atv:refpy="541.333">
   <atv:argument value="AGENT.OBJECTS.Test.SVH02_6.L01.Bsk.Bsk265Y1" name="base"/>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mfgmndsw/